# Beta version of Android OS

Tags: android

I am fairly new to the world of **Android** and am trying to get up to speed. I want to know if there is a way to get my hands on the **beta software versions** of the operating systems that Android might be releasing for its phones prior to its official launch (like Apple does. Apple releases the beta version of the software to developers, and recently to other users as well). I want to do this, so that I can test my software on the beta version and get an idea of how compatible it is with the newer software. I do not want to test it on the emulator, and rather physically load the beta version on an Android device.

So, I want to know if there is any way to get hands on the beta versions and how to know about a new released beta version. Also, I am highly confused about loading new versions of software on any android device externally. I read about it and got a whole lot confused about Flashing the ROM, rooting the device, and many others.

I will highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to get my hands on the beta software versions of the operating systems that Android might be releasing for its phones prior to its official launch

That has only been possible twice in the history of Android. When that occurs, you will be able to download developer preview editions from http://developer.android.com like everybody else.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I had absolutely no clue about it, and even the android developer site said nothing.